# Mongoose search multiple fields

Tags: node.js, search, mongoose, full-text-search, mongoose-schema

All,

Trying to implement simple search with NodeJS and Mongoose.

Not really sure where do I go wrong, trying to build up the query like so:

```
const query = Post.find();
if (value.searchQuery && value.city && value.category) {

        console.log("city and category");
        query.where({
            $or: [{ title: value.searchQuery }, { description: value.searchQuery }],
            city: value.city,
            category: value.category
        });

    } else if (value.searchQuery && value.city && !value.category) {

        console.log("No category");
        query.where({
            $or: [{ title: value.searchQuery }, { description: value.searchQuery }],
            city: value.city
        });

    } else if (value.searchQuery && value.category && !value.city) {

        console.log("No city");
        query.where({
            $or: [{ title: value.searchQuery }, { description: value.searchQuery }],
            category: value.category
        });

    } else if (value.searchQuery && !value.city && !value.category) {

        console.log("No city and no category");
        query.where({
            $or: [{ title: value.searchQuery }, { description: value.searchQuery }]
        });
```

Basically, what I have is search field, with city and category filters and user can either search by one field (city, category or searchQuery) or by all or just two.

P.s I'm relatively new to mongoose so take it easy ;)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you want and condition with city, category and with searchval?? Please tell me clearly your requirements ??

Comment: Yes, there are several options for search: 1) Query only 2) Query + City 3) Query + Category, 4) Query, city and category. Please note, query can search in title and description

Comment: Are you want to AND conditions with all fields ??

Comment: Only as stated above. 1) Query only 2) Query + City 3) Query + Category, 4) Query, city and category

Comment: Has to be partial search, if any words matcha in title/ description. Doesn't have to match all words if you know what i mean :) Normal search

Comment: { $and: [
    {
      $or: [{title: value.searchQuery },{description: value.searchQuery}]
    },                                                                                                            
    {category: value.category},                                                           
    {city:value.city}                                                                                                      
    ] }

Comment: This works yes, but only for full text search. Lets say, title is: This is some very long title... and query is "some" it doesn't find it. Is there a way to do partial search? With this query you need to include full text to match.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try this query

```
   let regex = new RegExp(value.searchQuery,'i');
   { $and: [ { $or: [{title: regex },{description: regex}] }, {category: value.category}, {city:value.city} ] }
```

Comment: This works yes, but only for full text search. Lets say, title is: This is some very long title... and query is "some" it doesn't find it. Is there a way to do partial search? With this query you need to include full text to match.

Comment: Please use regExp keyword for searching title and descriptaion